# PHP Suggestion form

Tags: php, forms, validation

i have been trying to make a suggestion form in my website but i cant succeed!
Here is my code

```
<div class="suggest" id="suggest">
<center>
<span class="title">Suggest a Game</span>

<br> 
<br>
<form action="suggest.php" method="get">
<input type="text" class="suggestion" id="suggestion" name="suggestion">   
<input onclick="validate()" type="submit" value="Send" class="send">  
</form>
<br>
<center>
<span id="validator"></span>
</center>
</div>
```

And PHP (suggest.php):

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['suggestion']))  {

//Email information
$admin_email = "greglypet@gmail.com";
$suggest = $_REQUEST['suggestion'];
$subject = "Game Suggestion:";
//send email
mail($admin_email, "$subject", "$suggest" );

echo }

else  { 

?>
```

Javascript (validate):

```
function validate() {  
var text = document.getElementById("suggestion").innerHTML;
if (text.length > 4) {
document.getElementById("validator").style.color = "lightgreen" ; 
document.getElementById("validator").innerHTML = "Thanks for the suggestion" ;  
}
 if (text.length < 4) { 
document.getElementById("validator").style.color = "red" ; 
document.getElementById("validator").innerHTML = "Input is too sort" ;  

}     

}
```

What am i doing wrong! I am a total noob at php, so please help!

What i want is to validate the text input length with validatetrue() and validatefalse(), however it doesnt seem to work!

Comment: What happens currently? `validatetrue` is outputted? You don't get the email?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is failing? Do you have the validatetrue(); and validatefalse(); functions somewhere?

Comment: maybe i wasnt clear :(. What i need is, if the input is short the validator will turn t red and stop the proceedure, and if the input is longer than 4 then the validator turns into green and sends the mail

Comment: Okay, where is the `validate` function? This is going to be done with JS, not PHP; or if you want PHP to check the length you'll need an ajax call.

Comment: you gave me a great idea, thanks dude really

Comment: so, so i made some changes, however whatever i type in the suggestion box, the validator always turn red and say "input is too short", is there something wrong with the js script?

Comment: you mistake is here: `var text = document.getElementById("suggestion").innerHTML;`. An `input` doesn't have innerHtml but a value! so it should be: `var text = document.getElementById("suggestion").value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your js-function `validate()` you have now:

```
var text = document.getElementById("suggestion").innerHTML;
```

But an input doesn't have this property/attribute, so it'll always return undefined (and therefor be smaller than 4).

To get the text of an input use `value`:

```
var text = document.getElementById("suggestion").value;
```